# Helping to create style similar to accordian - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently implementing a set of tabs similar to the style of an accordian.

This is my code so far...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uqBnH

I am having trouble closing the others when one is selected.

My jQuery code...

```
$(function(){

 $('.panel').hide();
  $('.mobtabs').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();        
  });
 });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just toggle the others shut with:

```
$(function () {
    $('.panel').hide();
    $('.mobtabs').click(function () {
        $('.mobtabs').not($(this)).next().hide();
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HrWGF/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(function () {
    $('.panel').hide();
    $('.mobtabs').click(function () {
        var nextPanel = $(this).next();
        $('.panel').not(nextPanel).hide();
        nextPanel.toggle();
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MrQ6m/)**

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes (I added the sliding) -

```
$('.panel').hide();
$('.mobtabs').click(function(){
    $('.mobtabs').not( $(this) ).next().slideUp(); // close them all
    $(this).next().slideToggle(); // slide open (or closed if it applies) this tab       
});
```